# ansible check file name with differnt string case , can i implemant if/else?

Tags: ansible

I have this case which in different conditions i can have the same file name but with different string cases: thetest.log or TheTest.log
and then the third task checking the log_result.
only thetest.log exsist.  so
it fails as the second task even though it skipped it set the log_result but not as file.
so I'm getting error :

```
 msg: |-
    The conditional check 'log_result.stat.exists == True' failed. The error was: error while evaluating conditional (log_result.stat.exists == True): 'dict object' has no attribute 'stat'





- name: Check if thetest.log exists in path
  stat:
    path: "{{ ansible_env.APP }}/thetest.log"
  register: log_result

- name: Check if TheTest.log exists in p_home
  stat:
    path: "{{ ansible_env.APP }}/TheTest.log"
  register: log_result
  when: name_var.stdout is match("foo")

- name: Create temporary log folder
  file:
    path: "{{ ansible_env.APP }}/log_tmp"
    state: directory
  when: log_result.stat.exists == True
```

can't i implement simple if/else 
that say:

```
if thetest.log exist
log_result = stat from thetest.log
else 
log_result = stat from TheTest.log
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ansible do not have plain if-else construct and will register variable even if the task is skipped. Your best bet here is to use two different variables for checking the existence of each file and then write the third condition as appropriate like so.

```
- name: Check if thetest.log exists in path
  stat:
    path: "{{ ansible_env.APP }}/thetest.log"
  register: log_result_1

- name: Check if TheTest.log exists in p_home
  stat:
    path: "{{ ansible_env.APP }}/TheTest.log"
  register: log_result_2
  when: name_var.stdout is match("foo")

- name: Create temporary log folder
  file:
    path: "{{ ansible_env.APP }}/log_tmp"
    state: directory
  when: log_result_1.stat.exists or (log_result_2 is not skipped and log_result_2.stat.exists)
```

Please check the [documentation here](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_variables.html#registering-variables) too.

---

**UPDATE**

Just another approach to check both files in one task then collect the result in one variable using [set_fact](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/set_fact_module.html)

```
- name: Check multiple file stat
  stat:
    path: "{{ item }}"
  loop:
    - "{{ ansible_env.APP }}/thetest.log"
    - "{{ ansible_env.APP }}/TheTest.log"
  register: file_stats

- set_fact:
    result: "{{ file_stats.results[0].stat.exists or file_stats.results[1].stat.exists }}"

- debug:
    var: result
```

Comment: can't i just somehow check in one task if the file is in  either case ? something like :
register: (if file =="thetest.log" if not file = "TheT)est.log") 
right in the register level ?

Comment: also when running the example and the log_result_2 not found 
it gives me error:
'dict object' has no attribute 'stat'

Comment: I have added an update to do the stat in one task. Please have a look.

Comment: Thanks! but i need 1 variable, in the end, to use not array with 1 element
can i set the result of this loop to 1 single register?  for example :
log_result =file_stats.results[0]

Comment: You can use [set_fact](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/set_fact_module.html) module to store the result in one variable then use that in the remaining plays. Updating the code.

Comment: can it be ?:
- set_fact:
    log_result: "{{ log_result_1.stat.exists or log_result_2.stat.exists }}"

Comment: should work too but you need to check `skipped` for second file otherwise you may get error.

Comment: yeah im getting error :
The task includes an option with an undefined variable. The error was: 'dict object' has no attribute 'stat'

Comment: `log_result_1.stat.exists or (log_result_2 is not skipped and log_result_2.stat.exists)`

Comment: yes. set_fact: log_result: "{{ log_result_1.stat.exists or (log_result_2 is not skipped and log_result_2.stat.exists) }}"

Comment: im getting this error:
The conditional check 'log_result_1.stat.exists or log_result_1.stat.exists' failed. The error was: error while evaluating conditional (log_result_1.stat.exists or log_result_1.stat.exists): 'bool object' has no attribute 'stat'

Comment: no sorry Private property of the company I'm working in

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/213140/discussion-between-user63898-and-mamun).

Comment: ok, basically both pieces of code I have posted work fine. You just need to add set_fact as commented.